# Clojure: character literal equality

Tags: string, clojure, character

I presumed, somewhat naively perhaps, that single character strings in Clojure would be equal regardless of how they were generated.

```
(= "G" "G")
=>
true

(= "G" \G)
=>
false

(= \G \G)
=>
true
```

Turns out not to be the case. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A character is *not* the same as a single-character string. Rather, a single-character string can be thought of as a sequence whose first and only item is a character.

```
(type "G")
;=> java.lang.String
(type \G)
;=> java.lang.Character

(count "G")
;=> 1
(count \G)
;=> UnsupportedOperationException count not supported on this type: Character

(seq "G")
;=> (\G)
(seq \G)
;=> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Character

(first "G")
;=> \G
(first \G)
;=> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Character
```

Comment: Additional explanation and practice is also available as part of the [Clojure Koans](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans)

Answer (score 5):

Just for the sake of completeness... ClojureScript, unlike Clojure, behaves exactly as the OP presumed. Since Javascript does not have the character type, just String, ClojureScript characters are implemented as single-character strings.

In ClojureScript REPL:

```
(= "G" "G")
;=> true

(= "G" \G)
;=> true

(= \G \G)
;=> true

(type "G")
;=> #object[String "function String() {
;=>    [native code]
;=> }"]

(type \G)
;=> #object[String "function String() {
;=>    [native code]
;=> }"]
```